How to compile a project to ESM + CJS and have one file different?
I want to compile my TS project to both ESM and CJS. I've set up two tsconfig files to do that and so on.
One of the files tries to conditionally import packages, which is something that has to be done differently in each environment. This means I have to have two different versions of the file. But I want the rest of my code to be the same.
Is there a way I can make sure that when the ESM version imports the file, it will receive one version while the CJS version will receive another?
I'd like to minimize using bundlers and post-build tools and processes as much as possible.

To conditionally import module in CJS, you do the following:
// try-import-cjs.js
try {
  var mod = require("something")
  console.log("Imported successfully"
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Package not found")
}

To reproduce the same behavior in ESM, I have to use a module-level await.
// try-import-esm.js
try {
  var mod = await import("something")
  console.log("Imported!")
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Package not found")
}

try-import-esm.js will only execute under ESM. A module-level await is a syntax error in a CJS context, so two different files are needed.
I want the rest of my code to be the same. So only this file will be different. Unlike in the examples above, both would have the same name, e.g. try-import.
In the TypeScript source code, I would write:
import {x} from "./try-import.js"

And this would import a different version of the file, depending on the compilation result being used.

The purpose of this whole thing is to automatically import and use any popular test frameworks the user has installed.
By saying 'conditional,' I mean that the package should be imported if it exists, but if it doesn't exist the program shouldn't crash. This should happen during the import itself.
However, I'm not asking about importing packages. I'm asking about TypeScript compilation.

Show the conditional import and explain why that is necessary. Also, you can use import() to load the conditional stuff and not need two versions, depending on what you’re importing.

I'm trying to automatically interface with the testing framework of the user, but I don't know which one it is so I try various things, including importing packages like ava and so on. This needs to happen with the loading of my package. If it's ESM I can await import(...) at module level and if it's CJS I require instead. But CJs can't do a top-level await.

@morganney It's a bit of a design choice. While the package would offer the ability to explicitly state the library, it would be convenient for the user if it "just worked."

@morganney The title of the question is what I'm asking. It's also in bold. You are trying to solve a problem I don't have.

You are saying that this is easier than just... having a single file different between the two builds?

I’ve deleted my answer until it can be made more clear whether your lib is intended to be imported as a side effect only, or whether it has exports that depend upon the conditional loading of the test frameworks, i.e. the export references the test framework somehow. I’d be happy to reopen/rework my answer if you can provide an example of how a consumer imports and uses your lib.

You can use conditional exports in your package.json -
{
  "exports": {
    "import": "./index-module.mjs",
    "require": "./index-require.cjs"
  },
  "type": "module"
}

When your package is included in ESM -
import * as MyPackage from "my-package" // index-module.mjs

When your package is include with CommonJS -
const MyPackage = require("my-package") // index-require.cjs

Make sure to read the docs, there's a lot of flexibility -
{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./index-module.mjs",
      "require": "./index-require.cjs"
    },
    "./something": "./src/something.js",
    "./components/*": {
      "require": "./src/components/*.cjs",
      "default": "./src/components/*.mjs"
    }
  },
  "type": "module"
}

import * as MyPackage from "my-package"
// index-module.mjs

import something from "my-package/something"
// src/something.js

import LoginForm from "my-package/components/LoginForm"
// src/components/LoginForm.mjs

const MyPackage = require("my-package") // index-require.cjs

const something = require("my-package/something")
// src/something.js

const LoginForm = require("my-package/components/LoginForm")
// src/components/LoginForm.cjs

